# Biblioteca para criar desenhos com imagens dinamicamente para ReactJS?

Tags: react

Olá. Alguém conhece uma biblioteca gráfica ou de desenhos para ReactJS que possa fazer algo parecido com isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de uma biblioteca gráfica que possibilite criar formas geométricas ou inserir imagens em locais específicos da tela, conforme a imagem acima, tudo dinamicamente. 
Na imagem acima, cada coisa na tela é um componente com uma imagem nele.
Se não ficou muito claro, comentem e explico melhor.